# skip_billing_check for reCaptcha Enterprise migration

Tags: recaptcha-enterprise

I'm trying to migrate a v2 reCaptcha to the Enterprise version, but I keep getting the error:

"FAILED_PRECONDITION: No billing account is linked to your GCP project. A billing is not mandatory for migrating. But any request above the free quota will return an error (see https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/quotas). If you still want to proceed, confirm by setting the skip_billing_check field to true."

I tried migrating by clicking on "upgrade key", as well as entering the cloud shell command. I keep getting the same billing error. I want to skip the billing check, but don't know how to set this flag. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use curl to set the argument

```
curl -X POST \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
    -d "" \
    "https://recaptchaenterprise.googleapis.com/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/keys/SITE_KEY:migrate?skip_billing_check=true"
```

The above command is taken from https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/migrate-recaptcha#rest-api by selecting the REST API tab and picking curl and adding the `skip_billing_check` paramter

[image]